# Ping a destination through several routes simultaneously

Tags: ip, routing

Let's say I have a `device_1`, `device_2` and `device_3` connected to a VPN 10.10.10.0/24 via `eth0`.

Let's also say that `device_1` and `device_2` are in the same local network 192.168.168.0/24 via `wlan0`.

Now, if I allow ipv4 forwarding and let `device_1` and `device_3` knows that they can also reach themselves via `device_2` using `ip route` then `device_1` and `device_3` have now 2 ways to reach each other.

As far as I know route always have priorities therefore if I were to ping `device_3` from `device_1`, the route with the highest priority will be chosen.

What I want to do is, when pinging `device_3` from `device_1` (and vise-versa) how can I make the ping going through BOTH routes ? Is it possible ?

> I'm well aware that redundancy will happens, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi Maxime and welcome. When you say you want to send a ping using both routes, do you mean that you want to test one route, and then test the other route? Or are you trying to send a packet down two paths at exact same time? I would assume you mean the first, because the second isn't normally possible. Are you just trying to test and verify that a failover connection is working?

Comment: Is there a reason why `ping -I` can't be used to send it through a particular interface?

Comment: Hello and thanks for your welcome and answer. Well, what I want is `to send a packet down two paths at exact same time` so what you said is "normally impossible" ..

In my system having to constantly change route priorities wouldn't be ideal. I would rather send packet using both routes.

Comment: Could you do that by mirroring as described in the answer to your other question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/604939/handle-2-routes-to-the-same-destination-simultaneously

Comment: telech, I actually missed that answer for some reason ! Will check tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

No you can't make one ping got through both routes at the same time. However you can write a script, that sends out a ping, then changes the NIC metrics sends out a second ping (obviously on the other route) and changes the metric back. The "route-starting-point" (the NIC) with the higher metric is always the one being used, unless it's down, then automaticaly the other one is used.

But as far as I understand you just want to test if both routes work, in case one goes down, right?

**Edit**: Well since there seems to be an goal not stated in your question I'll take a step back. Tetech suggestion could be a solution but that depends on the problem. It does not work for every scenario. More information on your part is required especially what exactly you mean by "making a ping go trough both routes". Maybe I simply missunderstood your question.

Comment: Well, the problem is at a higher level. But I feel that if I'm able to ping at the same time THEN i'll be able to solve the higher problem which is communicating using ROS via several route that reach a single destination. If I can make my ping go through 2 routes at the same time then I assume ROS will too.

Comment: @Maxime one ping can only take one route, there's no way around that. You need to clearify what you need to do.

Comment: The ping packet can be mirrored to another interface using `iptables` or the `tc` subsystem, so I would say it can be done.

Comment: @tetech well if you dublicate a paket essentially you have two pakets, not one, which of course can take two routes. This might solve the OPs problem in certain cases, but in others it does not. So essentially more information about the "higher problem" is required - hence my "question" or rather call to clearify his goal.

Comment: @tetech never mind I just realized your note that this might be a cross post... I think in this case I missunderstood his intend.

Comment: @Albin It does seem like a niche case with some background split between two questions.